# Is there any clever way to persist a previous reducer state in an ngrx angular application?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

At first let me present you with an overview of the problem.

In the app that I'm working on there's a *comment* functionality.
I'm holding all the comments in an array. Once one of them gets created/updated/deleted the sockets are letting all the users know that it happend and a reducer handles the incoming information by altering the previous state array and returning a new one.

Each of the comments may have a number of answers (one-level deep) and they are returned from the back-end as an array property of the parent comment. Creating/updating/deleting an answer to a comment results in an update action on the parent and as such is being processed by the back-end and results in a socket incoming to all the users and altering all of their comment arrays.

Now for the view part: the comments are displayed as a list of parent comments and when a user wants to show/update/delete/create an answer, they click on a button that displays all the answers and allows them to perform a desired action. As you may figure out, any action performed on the answers results in a refresh of a whole list of the parent comments. Since the comment component is by default set to hide its answers, creating a new reply immediately hides it from the user forcing him to reopen the answers box.

And that's an undesirable outcome which I'm struggling to fix right now.
I'm aware that it might sound like I'm fighting with the concept of immutability here, but also hope that some of you may give me some clever ideas as how to solve such an issue in a proper and elegant manner.

Thanks in advance for all the help

Comment: Can you please provide some code? Comment component, selectors, reducers etc. Questions like this are likely to be down voted and closed.

Comment: you can try keeping track of the widget state either in your "parent" component or the reducer. if you keep a record of parentCommentId to true/false value depending on the state of the widget, that should help fix your issue

Comment: My comment is going to be as much general as your question is general: you might want to preserve a fragment (slice) of your state, and refer to it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

As others have told you in comments it's hard to know what's going on without the actual code, but based on what you said I'm going to bet you should be using trackBy on the *ngFor you are likely using to display the comments.

The idea of using trackby is to let ngFor know that even if the object did change, it might still be the same, based on id/index/whatever you decide to trackby, and avoid recreating the DOM.